# Regex for multiple file paths

Tags: python, regex

I want to match files located in multiple directories. The file could be located in various depths of a directory, for example:

`/root_dir/a.txt`

or `/root_dir/dir_a/b.txt`

or `/root_dir/dir_b/dir_d/c.txt`

I tried the following regular expression:

`(('/root_dir')[^/.]+['.txt'])`

but it seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Your regex matches `'`, `/`, `r`, `o`, `o`, `t`, `_`, `d`, `i`, `r`, `'` (i.e. the string `"'/root_dir'"`), followed by 1 or more characters that are not `/` or `.`, followed by a character that is either `'` or `.` or `t` or `x`.

Comment: Why not `s.split("/")[-1]`?

Comment: Did you search for it on SO?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Thank you <3. Please write it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @revo of course I did :)

Comment: `re.match("/root_dir/(.*/|)[^/]+[.]txt$", line)` for each `line`. Assuming you want any `.txt` file with at least one character in the name preceding the extension. If you did not use `match` method, start with `^`.

Comment: @Cheshie Can you confirm that you are trying to match the full string and not just extract the filename? If so, you should use Wiktor's solution. Otherwise, I am happy to post my regex as an answer.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I'm trying to match the full string. Your answer is the one I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Actually not 100% what is a desired match, but above suggested `^\/root_dir[^.]+\.txt$` also matches for instance `/root_dir-do_not_match.txt`. I.e. not just files under the `/root_dir/` directory. Is that OK? But yeah, question is, do you really need to use regex? Or would treating and parsing the entries as filenames be an option?

Comment: Yeah, `^\/root_dir\/[^.]+\.txt$` is probably more accurate.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness right, that is simpler if I actually do not care about creating groups for filename or such. My instinct made me over complicate my regex a bit. :)

Comment: This question is a common problem which asks for a string that begins with and ends to a known delimiter. I marked this question as a duplicate. If you feel the marked question doesn't provide an answer for you please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Just a note, you are omitting all directories with a period in them. `^/root_dir/.*\.txt$` is fine.

Comment: @revo Good point